# Using yq to modify yml files

Tags: bash, yaml, yq

I am trying to add new arrays to the existing yml file

for example the test.yml looks like this

```
visibility:
  subscribe:
    enabled: true
    type: authenticated
  view:
    enabled: true
    type: public
```

and I am trying to modify it to look like this

```
visibility:
  subscribe:
    tags: []
    orgs: []
    enabled: true
    type: authenticated
  view:
    tags: []
    orgs: []
    enabled: true
    type: public
```

I have used yq to do that but there seems to be an issue it does not add any new field
Here is the bash script I made

```
yq '.visibility.subscribe |= {"orgs":"[]"} + .' test.yml
yq '.visibility.subscribe |= {"tags":"[]"} + .' test.yml
yq '.visibility.view |= {"orgs":"[]"} + .' test.yml
yq '.visibility.view |= {"tags":"[]"} + .' test.yml
```

Am I using the right logic ?

Comment: Which version of yq? There are two different tools under that name, and they have _extremely_ different syntax.

Comment: Mind, `"[]"` is very much not the same as `[]`

Comment: ...for a working approach in action, see https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/OrnatePitifulDevelopments#main.sh. Note that its output isn't syntactically identical to what you state you want, but it is _semantically_ identical: any valid YAML parser will treat it as the same.

Comment: Thank you @CharlesDuffy I was able to figure out the right syntax issue is resolved, I appreciate you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that you're using the yq tool that wraps jq (which appears to be the case from your starting syntax):

```bash
yq '
  .visibility.subscribe.orgs = []
| .visibility.subscribe.tags = []
| .visibility.view.orgs = []
| .visibility.view.tags = []
' test.yml
```

...is a simpler way to achieve output that's semantically identical (not necessarily syntactically identical!) to your stated/desired output. The most important change necessary was changing `"[]"` to `[]`.

Note that the new document is written to stdout -- `test.yml` is not modified in-place unless the `-i` argument is used.